# How to show cocos2d-js Animations by UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, cocos2d-js

How to show cocos2d-js Animations by UIWebView.

I try to load html to the UIWebView,in the html, to call the javascript to load the armatures,such as:

```
cc.spriteFrameCache.addSpriteFrames("res/Cowboy0.plist"); // 1
```

when i call

```
try{
        ccs.armatureDataManager.addArmatureFileInfo("res/Cowboy.ExportJson");
   }catch(e){
       alert(e.name + ":" + e.message);
}
```

it throws that cannot find the resource.

any one help. i thougth i may something wrong with the resource loading, but i try a lot of way,

```
webView loadHTMLString: baseURL:

webView loadRequest:
```

but cannot success...

Comment: Are you sure `"res/Cowboy.ExportJson"` is ok? Is it not something like `"res/CowboyExport.json"`?

Comment: yes, we use cocostudio tool to make the animation, so it is the ExportJson file come from. why i think it's maybe the resource load problem because we load the html from our server,the animation is show very well...

Comment: What webserver are you using for running thing in your local machine?